# Python file.write slows down as the output file grows bigger

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.7, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm very new to Python, but I have an aching problem.
I have received a program which reads an infile (text), changes some values, and writes an outfile (also text).
As the outfile grows bigger, the writes get slower and slower, making it unbearably slow after some 2 MB.
Why can this be? I have tried altering the code to use buffers of different sizes, and I have changed it to cache the data into larger chunks (a string) before writing. I also tried join instead of += to create the string to be written. NONE of these do any difference at all to performance - except writing bigger chunks, which actually made the code SLOWER.(!!!)

Here is the method that writes the outfile. I moved the write portion from a separate method to inline:

```
for ifile in _file_stripper(f_in):
    parse_infile(ifile)
    date = variable_data['arkiveringsdatum']
    variable_data['arkiveringsdatum'] = datetime( int(date[0:4]), int(date[4:6]), int(date[6:8]), tzinfo=TZ()).isoformat('T')
    _personnr= variable_data['personnr'].replace('-', '').split(' ')[0]
    tmplist = ['<utskriftsstatus><brevid_kalla>', variable_data['brevid_kalla'], '</brevid_kalla><mapp>Se Allt</mapp><tidpunkt>', variable_data['arkiveringsdatum'], '</tidpunkt><dokumentpaket>', variable_data['dokumenttyp'], '</dokumentpaket><status>Utskriven</status><rensningsdatum>999999</rensningsdatum><kundid_gdb>', variable_data['kundid_gdb'], '</kundid_gdb><personnr>', _personnr, '</personnr></utskriftsstatus>']
    f_out.write(''.join(tmplist))
```

Method `_file_stripper` splits a big file into records.
Infiles are 5-21 MB.

Please advice where to look for the error.
When I talk about slowdown, the write speed falls down below 4KB written/second after around 1 MB has been written, and it keeps falling as the outfile grows bigger.

EDIT: On request, here is parse_infile and _file_stripper:

```
def parse_infile(f_in):
   index = ""     #variabel som håller vilken ondemandvariabel vi läser in
   found_data = 0  #1 ifall vi hittat det vi letar efter annars 0
   for row in f_in:
      if( 'personnr' in row):
         found_data=1
         index = "personnr"
      elif( 'kundid_gdb' in row):
         found_data=1
         index = "kundid_gdb"
      elif( 'brevid_kalla' in row):
         found_data=1
         index = "brevid_kalla"
      elif( 'arkiveringsdatum' in row):
         found_data=1
         index = "arkiveringsdatum"
      elif( 'GROUP_FILENAME' in row ):
         variable_data['dokumenttyp'] = row.split(':')[-1].split('.')[2].capitalize()
      elif(found_data==1):
         variable_data[index] = row.split(':')[1].strip() 
         index = ""  #Nollställ index ifall värden saknas i filen
         found_data=0
      else:
         pass

def _file_stripper(tot_file):
   try:
      myfile = []
      for rows in tot_file:
         if not 'GROUP_FILENAME' in rows:
            myfile.append(rows)
         else:
            myfile.append(rows)
            yield myfile
   except Exception:
      pass

variable_data = { "brevid_kalla": "", "arkiveringsdatum": "", 
          "kundid_gdb": "", "personnr": "",
          "dokumenttyp": "" }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I of course tried file.open for the outfile with "w" as well as with "a". No difference.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add more detail.

Comment: Can you show us the definitions of `_file_stripper()` and `parse_infile()` too please?

Comment: Input data is in records with a fixed number of rows per record, with data sought for in FIELDNAME <CR/LF> FIELD VALUE <CR/LF> pairs.

Comment: Are you only expecting there to be five records in each file? Otherwise the logic of parse_infile seems like it might be wrong.

Comment: George: A record consists of 9 field/value pairs, five of them are captured into the variable_data, as they need to be modified before they are written. (The rest are kept as is.) Each new record has new values for those five fields you see listed - they are not records themselves, but parts of each record. There are thousands of records in each file.

Comment: (EDIT: Of course only the VALUE part is captured, the field name itself is merely used for navigating.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `_file_stripper` function adds to the `myfile` list endlessly, without ever reseting the list:

```
def _file_stripper(tot_file):
   try:
      myfile = []
      for rows in tot_file:
         if not 'GROUP_FILENAME' in rows:
            myfile.append(rows)
         else:
            myfile.append(rows)
            yield myfile
   except Exception:
      pass
```

Note that `myfile` is set outside the loop, and each row is appened to `myfile`, then yielded as is. Your process memory footprint will thus grow and grow, forcing the OS to start swapping out memory eventually, thus slowing your process to a crawl.

I think you meant to reset `myfile` when `GROUP_FILENAME` doesn't appear in `rows`:

```
def _file_stripper(tot_file):
   try:
      myfile = []
      for rows in tot_file:
         if not 'GROUP_FILENAME' in rows:
            myfile.append(rows)
         else:
            myfile.append(rows)
            yield myfile
            myfile = []
   except Exception:
      pass
```

Comment: @LJB: I am pretty damn certain it is, if that's your actual code. :-)

Comment: I just want to confirm that this did indeed do the trick. I told the author of the code, and the myfile was intially a GENERATOR. He later changed the code and forgot to initialize it as needed. BIG THANKS for helping me find it!

Comment: Now, if there is a good way to mark this question as "Resolved", please do that... its not in the FAQ, AFAICS. :D

Comment: @LJB: Looks like you figured it out. :-) It is in the "How to Ask" section of the [FAQ#howtoask].

Answer (score 1):

Most likely what is going on is that your `variable_data`, or more likely, some fields in it, are growing up with each parsed file.

Your `parse_infile`  function is pprobably not reseting it and appending values of new files to values already there, making it grow larger for each file read - that would result in resources used in a (O² ) as you describe.

The best pratice there is not to rely on global variables - make your `parse_infile` function create a fresh dictionary on each interaction, and return it to the caller. On your main function, assign the return value of the function to your dictionary:

```
def parse_infile(file_):
    variable_data = {}
    (...)
    return variable_data

(...)
for ifile in _file_stripper(f_in):
    variable_data = parse_infile(ifile)
    (...)
```